# why it change data type automatically after some code

Tags: python-3.x, types

actually i was practicing code then this problem arrived

suppose this is my code:

```
import random
randomnumber=random.randrange(0,100)
print(randomnumber)
input_user=23 #now input_user is int
```

after some more code:

like this:

```
import random
randomnumber=random.randrange(0,100)
print(randomnumber)
input_user=23  #now input_user is str

while input_user !=randomnumber:
    input_user=0
    print("enter number")
    input_user=input()
    if input_user < randomnumber:
        print("very less")
    elif (input_user > randomnumber ):
        print ("very big")
    else:
        print("correct :"+randomnumber)
```

as you can see this is my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
input_user=input()
```

will make `input_user` as `str`ing, and you will lose whatever values was previously associated to it, unless you take action against it (i.e. assign it to another variable).

Note that when the line is:

```
input_user=23
```

`input_user` **IS** a `int`.

To make your code work, you can cast the result of `input()` before performing the comparison, e.g.

```
import random

random_number=random.randrange(0,100)
print('Random Number: ', random_number)

input_number = None
while input_number != random_number:
    input_number = int(input("enter number: "))
    if input_number < random_number:
        print("very less")
    elif (input_number > random_number):
        print("very big")
    else:
        print("correct: ", random_number)
```

Note that this is not a very robust way of handling your input, as not inserting a number will raise a `ValueError`.

A better approach could be to catch the error with a [`try`/`except`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) construct:

```
import random

random_number=random.randrange(0,100)
print('Random Number: ', random_number)

input_number = None
while input_number != random_number:
    try:
        input_number = int(input("enter number: "))
    except ValueError:
        input_number = None
    else:
        if input_number < random_number:
            print("very less")
        elif (input_number > random_number):
            print("very big")
        else:
            print("correct: ", random_number)
```

Comment: Very complete and thorough, I kind of chose to fix the immediate problem but this is definitely a more complete answer, hopefully OP sees this too

Answer (score 2):

Fixed for you

```
import random
randomnumber=random.randrange(0,100)
print(randomnumber)
input_user=23  #now input_user is str

while input_user !=randomnumber:
    print("enter number")
    input_user=int(input())
    if input_user < randomnumber:
        print("very less")
    elif input_user > randomnumber:
        print ("very big")
    else:
        print("correct :"+str(randomnumber))
```

The result from input() is ALWAYS a string, even if it is composed of numbers.

Comment: why not just do `int(input(...))` instead of converting everywhere?